# Django user input overrides global model

Tags: django

I’m new to Django and I’m creating a recipe website. I would like to have global ingredients that every user has by default, e.g bacon, eggs & etc. As well as, user created ingredients, e.g. Mom’s Sauce. Each ingredient can be assigned a category for where to find it in a grocery store, for example bacon can be found in Meat & Seafood section. What I’m struggling with is how I can allow users to change the category of a global ingredient, for example, if a user wants to change bacons category to ‘Deli’. How do I override that category for a specific user?

```
#models.oy
Ingredient(model.Models):
name = models.charField(max_length=100) #e.g bacon
category = models.charField(max_length=100) #e.g meat & seafood


GlobalIngredient(Ingredient):
pass


UserCreatedIngredient(Ingredient):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```